# Kivy: Dismiss One Popup From Another Popup

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I use `kivy.factory.Factory` to open the popups, but it's not working when I want to close them.

Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


x = Builder.load_string("""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

Screen:
    Button:
        text: 'Press to Open First Popup'
        on_press:
            F.FirstPopup().open()

<FirstPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'First Popup'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: Window.width / 1.4
    height: Window.width / 1.4

    Button:
        text: 'Press to Open Second Popup'
        on_press: F.SecondPopup().open()

<SecondPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Second Popup'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: Window.width / 1.8
    height: Window.width / 1.8

    Button:
        text: 'Press to Close Both Popups'
        on_press:
            root.dismiss()
            F.FirstPopup().dismiss() # < DOSEN'T WORK
""")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return x

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call `F.Foo()` you are creating a new object of the Foo class, so in your case `F.FirstPopup().open()` of the Screen is different from `F.FirstPopup().dismiss()` SecondPopup, in other words you are closing a popup that you have just created instead of the start. To make it obvious, you can change your code to:

```
# ...
Button:
    text: 'Press to Close Both Popups'
    on_press:
        print(F.FirstPopup())
```

Obtaining the following:

```
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f9a183e18>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc118>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc388>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc5f8>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc528>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc2b8>
<kivy.factory.FirstPopup object at 0x7f8f996fc048>
```

And as you see each time you press it you get a new id indicating that it is a new object.

So a possible solution is to save a reference of the object created by a property:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

x = Builder.load_string("""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

Screen:
    Button:
        text: 'Press to Open First Popup'
        on_press:
            F.FirstPopup().open()

<FirstPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'First Popup'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: Window.width / 1.4
    height: Window.width / 1.4
    Button:
        text: 'Press to Open Second Popup'
        on_press: 
            second_popup = F.SecondPopup()
            second_popup.first_popup = root
            second_popup.open()

<SecondPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Second Popup'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: Window.width / 1.8
    height: Window.width / 1.8
    first_popup: None
    Button:
        text: 'Press to Close Both Popups'
        on_press:
            root.dismiss()
            if root.first_popup is not None: root.first_popup.dismiss()
""")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return x

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: nice! That worked, thank you. I deleted the `first_popup: None` and `if root.first_popup is not None:` thought. It worked fine. What is the purpose of those, and will it be okay if I keep them out of my code?

Comment: @PetarLuketina Anyone does a code that works once, but a programmer must make a code that always works so the first point is to verify the existence of objects that are not explicitly declared.