# Kivy - popup A shows over popup B

Tags: python, multithreading, popup, kivy

**PROBLEM**

I have a loop that in every passage displays a popup. I will call it the popup_A. In the loop there is a condition that when is met it triggers together another popup and a method in a thread. This second popup I call popup_B. The problem is that that the popup_B it does show but right after that the popup_A shows over the popup_B, covering it fully. To picture better the get the idea of the flow:

```
def myFun:
    if condition1:
        method1
    if condition2:
        method2
    if condition3:
        show popup_B
        thread method3
    thread popup_A

def popup_A:
    do something
    display message_A
    call myFun
   
def popup_B:
    display message_B
```

**CODE**
The method involved in the looping:

```
def goForward(self):
        if  self.header == "someTask":
            if "tasks" in self.data:    # check if the request has "tasks" in the body
                if self.counter < len(self.data["tasks"]):  # check the counter
                    self.code = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("code")
                    action = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("actionDescription")
                    
                    if "myCondition" in str(action):
                            
                        #set the popup structure
                        self.popup_B = ActivityBox(self)
                        self.popup_B.open()
                        
                        # run the method in a thread
                        t1 = threading.Thread(target = timeConsumingMethod)
                        t1.start()
                    
                    # dismiss the popup ActivityBox     
                    self.popup_B.dismiss()

                    # call popup_A in thread
                    t3 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup_A)
                    t3.start()
                    
def do(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup.dismiss()
    self.goForward()

def cancel(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup.dismiss()
    self.goForward()

def popup_A(self):
    self.popup = MessageBox(self)
    self.popup.open()
```

The ActivityBox and MessageBox popups structure in the `Builder.load_string()`:

```
<MessageBox>:
    size_hint: 1, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "MessageBoxTitle"
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: "MessageBoxLabel"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 0,204,0,1
                text: "CONFIRM"
                on_press:
                    self.disabled = True
                    self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                    app.do()
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.cancel()
                    root.dismiss()

<ActivityBox>:
    size_hint: 1, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "ActivityBoxTitle"
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: "ActivityBoxLabel"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
```

**EXPLANATION OF THE CODE**
The components of the main loop are `goForward` and the popup_A. With every passage of the loop the popup_A appears, called in a thread. Then the popup_A calls back `goForward`. If the condition "work" in `goForward` is met, the "work in progress" popup_B shows up. The popup_B runs together with a method in a thread otherwise Kivy does not show the popup (locking GUI).

**RESULTS**

So far I have tried with:

1. Run the popup_B in a thread `t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup.open)`: the popup_A covers the popup_B.
2. Using the thread `.join()`: the popup_A appears but the popup_B does not, .join() ignores it.
3. Run the popup_B and the `timeConsumingMethod` together in a thread: the popup_A appears but the popup_B does not.
4. Run the `timeConsumingMethod` as a process: the popup_A appears but the popup_B does not, the program hangs.
5. Using `mutex = threading.Lock()` to lock the thread with the popup_B: the popup_A appears over the popup_B. Also the GUI gets garbled.
6. Run the popup_A not in a thread and run popup_B and the `timeConsumingMethod` together in a thread: the popup_A appears over the popup_B.

**QUESTION**

The popup_A can show up only after the method in the thread has finished and the popup_B has been dismissed. How can I prevent the popup_A to cover the popup_B?

I went over the posts below but I did not find a solution.

**--- UPDATE 20200715 ------------------------------------------------**

In the code I renamed the popup "work in progress" in **popup_B** and the popup2 in **popup_A** for a better understanding.

**--- UPDATE 20200716 -------------------------------------------------**

I modified the code using `Clock.schedule_once` for `step2`(thread for `popup_A` and `step3`(thread for the `timeConsumingMethod` and `popup_B`). The `popup_B` goes up but the `popup_A` covers it untill the last `popup_A` is dismissed with the button. To wait for the `timeConsumingMethod` to finish without the `popup_A` to fire up, I use a `while loop`. The code is below:

```
def goForward(self):
        if  self.header == "someTask":
            if "tasks" in self.data:    # check if the request has "tasks" in the body
                if self.counter < len(self.data["tasks"]):  # check the counter
                    self.code = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("code")
                    action = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("actionDescription")
                    
                    if "myCondition" in str(action):
                        self.returnStatus = 1 # set status  
                        #the two rows below give the same result
                        #self.popup_B = ActivityBox(self)
                        #self.popup_B.open()

                        Clock.schedule_once(self.step3)
                        
                        # run the method in a thread
                        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.step1)
                        t1.start()

                        while self.returnStatus != 0:
                            time.sleep(1)
                    
                    Cloch.schedule_once(self.step2)

def step1(self):
    ts1 = threading.Thread(target = self.timeConsumingMethod)
    ts1.start()
    ts1.join()
    self.returnStatus = 0 # change status when over
    return(self.returnStatus)

def step2(self, *args):
    ts2 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup_A)
    ts2.start()

def step3(self, *args):     
    #set the popup structure
    self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
    self.popup.open()
    
def popup_A(self):
    self.popup = MessageBox(self)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup.open)
    t3.start()

def do(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup.dismiss()
    self.goForward()

def cancel(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup.dismiss()
    exit()
```

1. [Correct way to implement loading popup in kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56058099/correct-way-to-implement-loading-popup-in-kivy-app)
2. [Kivy: Dismiss One Popup From Another Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245410/kivy-dismiss-one-popup-from-another-popup)
3. [Kivy Clock and Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901880/kivy-clock-and-popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have solved the issue of overlapping of the popups with the use of threading. I guess the issue is a matter of the sharing memory and the interpreter lock.

**THE CODE**

I modified the code and added `threading.Thread` to the methods `do(self)` and `cancel(self)` that are bind to the buttons of the popups. The `step1` runs the `timeConsumingMethod` in a thread, the `step2` calls the popup_A that runs in a thread and the `step3` runs the popup_B in a thread. This way popup_A does show and is dismissed when the popup_B shows up.

```
def goForward(self):
        if  self.header == "someTask":
            if "tasks" in self.data:    # check if the request has "tasks" in the body
                if self.counter < len(self.data):   # check the counter
                    if "myCondition":
                        self.step3()
                        self.step1()
                    self.popup_A()

def step1(self):
    self.popup_A.dismiss()  # dismiss the popup A first
    ts1 = threading.Thread(target = self.timeConsumingMethod)
    ts1.start()
    ts1.join()
    self.popup_B.dismiss()  # dismiss the popup B at the end

def step2(self, *args):
    self.popup_A()

def step3(self, *args):     
    #set the popup structure
    self.popup_B = ActivityBox(self)
    ts3 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup_B.open)
    ts3.start()
    ts3.join()
    
def popup_A(self):
    self.popup_A = MessageBox(self)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target = self.popup_A.open)
    t3.start()

def do(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup_A.dismiss()  # dismiss the popup A first
    td = threading.Thread(target = self.goForward)
    td.start()

def cancel(self):
    self.counter = self.counter + 1
    self.popup_A.dismiss()  # dismiss the popup A first
    tc = threading.Thread(target = self.goForward)
    tc.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the popup_A to not popup until the time consuming thread is finished is to call popup_A at the end of the time consuming thread. Try separating the `goForward()` method into two parts. The first part remains almost unchanged:

```
def goForward(self):
        if  self.header == "someTask":
            if "tasks" in self.data:    # check if the request has "tasks" in the body
                if self.counter < len(self.data["tasks"]):  # check the counter
                    self.code = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("code")
                    action = self.data["tasks"][self.counter].get("actionDescription")
                    
                    if "myCondition" in str(action):
                            
                        #set the popup structure
                        self.popup_B = ActivityBox(self)
                        self.popup_B.open()
                        
                        # run method in a thread
                        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.timeConsumingMethod)
                        t1.start()
```

I have moved the `timeConsumingMethod()` into the class, so it needs a call as `self.timeConsumingMethod` in the `Thread`.

Then place the rest of the old `goForward()` method in a separate method (I call it `step2()`):

```
def step2(self, *args):
    # dismiss the popup ActivityBox
    self.popup_B.dismiss()

    # call popup_A in thread
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.popup_A)
    t3.start()
```

Then in the `timeConsumingMethod()`, call `step2()` when it finishes:

```
def timeConsumingMethod(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.step2)
```

Comment: your approach is interesting but the flow must remain in the loop. The popup_A must appear with every passage. With your suggestion the popup_A does not show if the `condition3` is not met.

Comment: Perhaps just adding an `else:` block to the `if "myCondition" in str(action):` block that calls `self.step2()`. Of course, that will require some care to handle the case where `self.popup_B` has not been created.

Comment: I followed your suggestion @John Anderson and divided the loop in steps. Doing so I came to a `TypeError: step2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.` See update 20200716.

Comment: In your updated code posted here, `step2()` takes any number of positional arguments, not just 1.

Comment: Yes, it takes any number of positional arguments in order to avoid the TypeError.

Comment: The `Clock.schedule_once(self.step2)` passes an additional argument to whatever it calls. The additional argument is the `delta-time`.